# Object set of a clonal category.

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I read the statement that "a clonal category has a small set of objects", which I don't quite agree about. In the definition of clonal category, at least as it is given in that context, it is required that a bijection exist between its object-set and the set of natural numbers $\omega$. This, in my understanding, does not imply that this object-set is small. Do you agree or am I missing something? Thanks in advance for any answer of yours.

*PS* Yes, I did miss something. *My* oversight was that throughout the text the hypothesis is tacitly understood, that, though a category may have a large set of objects, these are always *small*, and of course a countable set of small sets is indeed small. Thanks to everybody though.

Comment: You must have a strange definition of "small" if it is not bijection-invariant...

Comment: @ Zhen Lin Well, given a universe $U$ a set is small (relative to $U$) if and only if it is a member of $U$. According, for instance, to Mac Lane. And this definition is the one used in the context I refer to. So being "small" has nothing to do with cardinality, it seems.

Comment: Yes, perhaps strictly speaking we should demand that, but it is clear that there is usually no harm in expanding the definition.

Comment: @Zhen Lin I may agree that there is no harm, but the author (G.M. Bergman) clearly distinguishes between "small" and "quasi-small"; it's his choice, not mine, and this statement of his seems to contradict his premisses. It's surely just an oversight, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Either an oversight or a deliberate abuse of terminology. Either way, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Zhen Lin As I said, throughout the text he's very careful to distinguish between the two concepts, and the oversight might be of a different kind, that is, some slipped condition in consequence of which a clonal category _does_ have a small set of objects. Anyway, I don't worry, the point is not that what follows doesn't stand on its legs...

Answer (score 0):

The set $\omega$ is surely small.

And every set in bijection with a small set is small (working in ZF for example, it is a special case of the *replacement axiom scheme*).

Comment: I'm not quite sure. This would imply that, in the universe $U$, the set $\{U\}$ is small, which contradicts the axiom of regularity. It is exactly for this reason that the term "quasi-small" is used instead.

Comment: @alex Yes you might be right. I leave the answer nevertheless (it will avoid others to do the same kind of answer).

Comment: ..and what is this "quasi-small" then?

Comment: @Berci A set is quasi-small if it is in bijection with a small set. Thus $\{U\}$ is quasi-small but not small.